# Re-train the decoder part of an encoder

Tags: python, machine-learning

Can the decoder of the pre-trained autoencoder be trained again by taking the feature vector of the Siamese Neural Network (SNN) as input?

I have trained the SNN model. Additionally, I trained autoencoder on the same dataset. The reconstruction of images is not satisfactory because of the small dataset. Now I want to take the feature vector of the SNN model(you can say the encoded part) and re-train the trained decoder of the autoencoder. My question is how can we take the feature vector from SNN and re-train the only decoder part of the autoencoder?

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to StackOverflow, Your question is better suited for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/
You should write your question according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Since your question does not involve any coding it is not suited for stackOverflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have trained the SNN model. Additionally, I trained autoencoder on the same dataset. The reconstruction of images is not satisfactory because of the small dataset. Now I want to take the feature vector of the SNN model(you can say the encoded part) and re-train the trained decoder of the autoencoder. My question is how can we take the feature vector from SNN and re train the only decoder part of autoencoder?

Comment: Please edit your question to add that information